# NullPointerException when integrating Processing into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am currently trying to integrate an existing Processing project into Eclipse. There are 2 classes, TagCloud and Tag, the former is the controller of the latter. In TagCloud, I have the following code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RELATIONS; i++) {
          println("i: " + i);
          tags.get(i).refTagsMap(tagsMap);
          tags.get(i).setLinks();
          //Randomly assign a location to  the first tag.
          System.out.println("Tag from map: " + tags.get(i));
          for(int j = 0; j < tags.size(); j++)
              System.out.println(j + " " + tags.get(j));
          tags.get(i).drawTag();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_RELATIONS; i++) {
          println("Drawing tags for tag: " + i); 
          tags.get(i).drawLinks();
        }
```

tags is an ArrayList of Tag objects, tagsMap is a HashMap of the type HashMap(String, Tag).
However, the code breaks at the `tags.get(i).drawTag()` method and displays the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10713)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10525)
    at TagCloud.main(TagCloud.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.noFill(PApplet.java:14574)
    at Tag.drawTag(Tag.java:65)
    at TagCloud.<init>(TagCloud.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10711)
    ... 2 more
```

Below are the `drawTag()` and `drawLink` methods

```
public void drawTag() {
  parent.noFill();
  parent.stroke(255);
  parent.strokeWeight(3);    
  float x = location.x;
  float y = location.y;
  //Create the rectangle frame
  frame = parent.createShape(parent.RECT, x, y, 100, 80);
  //Add it to the canvas
  parent.shape(frame);

  //Write the text
  parent.text(topic, x + 15, y + 25);
}


public void drawLinks() {
    System.out.println();
    parent.stroke(255);
    parent.strokeWeight(1);
    for(int i = 0; i < linkKeys.size(); i++)
    {
      Tag linkedTag = links.get(linkKeys.get(i));
      System.out.println(linkedTag);
      int x = (int)linkedTag.getLocation().x;
      int y = (int)linkedTag.getLocation().y;
      PShape line = parent.createShape(parent.LINE, location.x, location.y, x, y);
      //Add the shape to the 
      parent.shape(line);
      linkLines.add(line);
    }
  }
}
```

parent is a PApplet passed in Tag's constructor.

Comment: what line in the above sample is at TagCloud.main(TagCloud.java:97)

Comment: That is the main function call of Tags cloud: 
PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "TagCloud" });

Comment: I added a `System.out.println(parent)` line at beginning of `drawTag()`, and it prints the following: `TagCloud[panel0,0,0,0x0, invalid, layout=java.awt.FlowLayout]`, which means it isn't null, right?

Comment: refresh the page I made a mistake and edited it now

Comment: @Satre Yes. My analysis was incorrect. Even the stack trace shows it makes it into `noFill()` and `parent` is not `null`. Apologies for steering you wrong. The root cause is not in the code you've posted. Can you make your entire project available for download? (Or can you create a minimal example that reproduces this?)

Comment: the code is on github: [link](https://github.com/Satre95/Financial-Literacy/tree/Presentation-(Ecplise))

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the error. 
In the constructor of my `TagsCloud` object, I was initializing the `Tag` object and attempting to pass a ref to the TagsCloud object into it. However, the `TagsCloud` constructor has not finished executing and so the `TagsCloud` object has not yet been fully initialized, hence the `NullPointerException`